# Why does OCaml compiler give this error message regarding type inference?

Tags: ocaml

I have written this helper function in OCaml and it keeps throwing this error.

code:

```
let rec helper1 f lines d =
        match lines with
        | [] -> None
        | h::t when ( helper2 f h 0) <> -1 -> Some (d, (helper2 f h 0))
        | _::t -> helper1 f t d+1;;
```

error:

```
|_::t -> helper1 f t d+1;;
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type ('a * int) option
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

I need to have the type as `('a *int) option` and according to me it looks okay. I am new to OCaml and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems a pair of parentheses is missing → `helper1 f t (d+1);;`

Comment: Also, note that your question was not self-contained (the `helper2` function was not defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It a common problem when learning OCaml. You are assuming that,

```
f x+1
```

is interpreter as

```
f (x+1)
```

while in fact it means,

```
(f x) + 1
```

More formally, in OCaml the function application operator, which is denoted just as a juxtaposition of the function name and its arguments, has higher precedence (binds tighter, evaluated before) than infix operators (e.g., `+`, `-`, `*`, etc).

Now the error message has a clear explanation since you have

```
helper1 f t d + 1
```

the compiler sees that you add something (`helper1 f t d`) to `1` and infers that this something should have type `int`. On the other hand, from the other occurrences of `helper1` it also infers that it has type `('a * int) option`, which is clearly not an `int`. So it indicates an error.